# update user in another controller rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ruby-on-rails-3.1

In my rails app, if I go to localhost:3000/users/edit to update user

```
<h2>Edit <%= resource_name.to_s.humanize %></h2>

<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name), :html => { :method => :put }) do |f| %>
  <%= devise_error_messages! %>

  <div><%= f.label :email %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :email%></div>


  <div><%= f.label :password %> <i>(leave blank if you don't want to change it)</i><br />
  <%= f.password_field :password, :autocomplete => "off" %></div>

  <div><%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
  <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %></div>

  <div><%= f.label :current_password %> <i>(we need your current password to confirm your changes)</i><br />
  <%= f.password_field :current_password %></div>

  <div><%= f.submit "Update" %></div>
<% end %>

<h3>Cancel my account</h3>

<p>Unhappy? <%= button_to "Cancel my account", registration_path(resource_name), :data => { :confirm => "Are you sure?" }, :method => :delete %></p>

<%= link_to "Back", :back %>
```

It 's alright, but if I move this code ((or render this view) to another view of another controller  it 'll have an error :"undefined local variable or method `resource' for #<#:0x3b27478>"
I don't know how to fix it, any help really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`resource` is a variable set by the [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) gem. In order to move the above code somewhere else, it means that **you** will have to take care of setting the `resource` variable yourself.

Basically a rails `form_for` wants to take the instance of the object you want to create / edit.

```
<%= form_for instance_object ...
```

In your case you'll need to first fetch the user you want to edit (or use current_user) and then give it to the `form_for` helper method:

```
<%= form_for current_user ...
```

or by setting the `@user` instance variable in your controller first:

```
def new
  @user = User.new
end

def edit
  @user = User.find(some_id)
end
```

Then in your view:

```
<%= form_for @user ...
```

Don't forget to replace all the `resource` occurences by your instance variable.